# How to lock an object so that it is shown in the output of !dumpheap -thinlock?

Tags: c#, windbg

I am creating some sample programs in C# to demonstrate the usage of !SOS.syncblk, !SOSEX.dlk and other extensions available for WinDbg.

I have samples for all types of deadlocks (lock statement, ReaderWiterLock, ReaderWriterLockSlim and CriticalSection), but not thinlocks.

What is the code to create a thinlock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A thinlock is a lock which has no conflict in being accessed.
Perhaps the simplest program of demonstrating a thinlock is

```
class Program
{
    private static string l = "Demo lock resource";
    static void Main()
    {
        lock (l)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```

In WinDbg it is shown like this:

```
0:004> .loadby sos clr
0:004> !dumpheap -thinlock
 Address       MT     Size
02782448 67c4acc0       50 ThinLock owner 1 (0065cd98) Recursive 0
Found 1 objects.
```

dd can show the object header and method table:

```
0:004> dd 02782448-4 L2
02782444  80000001 67c4acc0
```